# Zero restrictions in state-space models/ Kalman Filter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, kalman-filter, state-space-models, constraint

I am estimating a state space model using Kalman and the EM algorithm in Matlab, using Kevin Murphy's toolbox (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/Kalman/kalman.html). My question should in principle by straightforward: I have several zero restrictions in the observation and state equation, meaning that some of the variables simply do not appear in some equations. How can I impose this condition in the system?

In a linear model where everything is observable I simply would not include these variables in the regressions, here the solution is not that obvious.

The obvious thing to do here is to simply impose the restrictions after the M-step, but if I do this then things fall apart fast.

Answer (score 1):

If your model is 
$$
   x_{t+1} = F x_t + w_t \\
   y_t   = H x_t + v_t,  
$$
where $w_t \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, Q)$ $x_0 \sim N(X_0, V_0)$ and $v_t \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, R)$, then your parameters are 
$$
(F,H,Q,R,X_0,V_0).
$$ 
Most of the time not all the elements of these matrices and vectors are unknown. If that is the case, then you can fix some of these elements, in your case, to zero. This does not affect filtering, smoothing, or parameter estimation.